# VBA: Split text in cell, create duplicate row for each element in cell

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem**

When I try to run the macro, I get a syntax error on the line "With Sheets("Sheet5").

[image]

I'm new to VBA but I believe I'm on the right track after finding [this example](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=181002) on another site.

**My Data**

I have a sheet with 10k records. In column K, I have a field "genres" which has string values delineated by a "|". An example being:

```
2015    32.985763   150000000   1513528810  124 6/9/15  5562    6.5 2015    137999939.3 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
```

The genres value is:

```
Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
```

**Expected Result**

What I am trying to do is split the values in the genre cells by the "|", and create a new row for each genre, and copy the values from the original row into the new row.

Using the data above as an example, I'd loop over the 4 genres, create 4 new rows and in the genres column, replace the 4 values with the 1 value for that for loop, and remove the original row. The result being:

```
2015    32.985763   150000000   1513528810  124 6/9/15  5562    6.5 2015    137999939.3 Action  
2015    32.985763   150000000   1513528810  124 6/9/15  5562    6.5 2015    137999939.3 Adventure   
2015    32.985763   150000000   1513528810  124 6/9/15  5562    6.5 2015    137999939.3 Science Fiction 
2015    32.985763   150000000   1513528810  124 6/9/15  5562    6.5 2015    137999939.3 Thriller
```

**The Function**

I've been working through understanding what happens in the example I found. I believe it is correct up to the for loop, but I'm confused by it errors at the With Sheets("Sheet5") line. The data is on Sheet5.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReorgData()
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long, s
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Sheet5”)
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = lr To 2 Step -1
            If InStr(.Cells(r, 11), “|") > 0 Then
                s = Split(Trim(.Cells(r, 11)), “|”)
                .Rows(r + 1).Resize(UBound(s)).Insert
                .Cells(r + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(s), 11).Value = .Cells(r, 1).Resize(, 11).Value
                .Cells(r, 12).Resize(UBound(s) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(s)
                .Cells(r + 1, 13).Resize(UBound(s), 3).Value = .Cells(r, 13).Resize(, 3).Value

            End If
        Next r
        .Columns(12).AutoFit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `”` to `"`

Comment: That did it - thanks! If you write that as the answer, I'll accept it too

Comment: Well laid out question Emile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `”` to `"`.  VBA requires standard double-quotation marks to act as string delimiters.

You will also have the same issue on the following lines:

```
        If InStr(.Cells(r, 11), “|") > 0 Then
            s = Split(Trim(.Cells(r, 11)), “|”)
```

---

I'm not sure whether this should be actually classified as a "simple typographical error" and therefore the question should be closed, but so many people have this issue that I'll leave this answer here until someone **does** close the question.

Comment: @A.S.H - It's the first thing I look for these days when someone says something simple like `Worksheets("Sheet1")` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks - as a VBA n00b, this is a great lesson